# Alternative GSON Fields

Tags: java, android, json, field, gson

So basically, I'm using GSON to parse some JSON on Android, and when grabbing a List of objects using JavaBeans I came across an issue - one of the object types has 2 variants

These 2 JSON objects are exactly identical except there can either be a String field (field 'a'), or an object field (field 'b')

Is it possible to get GSON to accept a JSON object with either one of these 2 options, and just leave the field that's not included in the JSON as null in the Java object?

Thanks

Comment: I know this isn't an answer, and it's not what you want to hear, but don't do that. Fix the model in JSON so that it's sensible. You'll thank yourself later. (And see creating a custom serializer/deserializer if you stay with the object that has two different types approach.)

Comment: Sadly I don't control the JSON (I'm just polling a 3rd party server for data), otherwise yes, I'd happily change the JSON format

Comment: I don't *think* GSON can handle the two types thing out of the box, but I will also admit I've never really tried to do that (what happens if you just make the type Object? *shudder*). It sounds to me like you may need a custom deserializer:https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Custom-Serialization-and-Deserialization.

Comment: The problem with just using an object is that the 2 variants have different field names... :/

And thanks, I'll take a look at that

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using either Jackson or Moshi for working with JSONs and avoid using Gson in your next project, as it is much slower for deserialization and while marginally faster than Moshi at serializing objects, the resulting JSON might be larger due to the HTML-compatible escape characters that Gson inserts into it.